# Solidworks to URDF for robot arm with complex joint's

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, inverse-kinematics

I've tried to create a URDF model of an arm robot similar to the following links using Solidworks to URDF plugin. This plugin creates a hierarchy relation between joint and links in any robot mechanism

https://grabcad.com/library/robot-arm-assembly-1

however, I've noticed this robot arm style has a couple of interaction links & joints that is not easy to make simple child-parent tree links.
I've trying to extract the child-parent link relations according to the following image
[image]

for example, the child-parent relation  of link 1 is not clear for me, however, I made the following child-parent tree according to that image
I really appreciated any tip that helps me verify my design
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to get a parent-child relationship with this because it's not a kinematic tree. You've got a [four-bar linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-bar_linkage), which is closed chain linkage. The angle that Link 2 makes with Link 1 depends on the angle at AxisX1 AND the distance from AxisX1 to AxisX3 AND the length of bar1 AND the length of link1 AND the distance from Axis4 to AxisX7.